# Activity closes after service stopped in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

Activity closes when service is stopped The code which i am using to start service is

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TService.class);
startService(intent2);
```

and the code to stop service is

```
 Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TService.class);
stopService(intent2);
```

i tried an alternative to use bind service but it showed the same behavior by closing the activity

code to start bind service was

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TService.class);
bindService(intent2, mServerConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
startService(intent2);
```

& code to stop bind service was

```
stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TService.class));
unbindService(mServerConn);
```

My service TService.class

```
public class TService extends Service {



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("service", "destroy");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.d("TAG", "service started");
        context = getApplicationContext();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```

My Activity MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    Button start,stop;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        start=(Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        stop=(Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);



        final ServiceConnection mServerConn = new ServiceConnection() {
               @Override
                public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "onServiceDisconnected");
                }

                @Override
                public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Log.d("LOG_TAG", "onServiceConnected");
                }
            };


        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TService.class);
                intent2.putExtra("value", "1");
                startService(intent2);

            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TService.class);
                intent2.putExtra("value", "2");
                stopService(intent2);


            }
        });


    }



    private int getClicks() {
        clickCount++;
        return clickCount % 2 == 0 ? R.drawable.start : R.drawable.stop;
    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (TService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

    }


}
```

I am really stuck on it ,any suggestion or solution will be accepted 
Thanks in advance

Comment: If my dose not works plz post complete code for Activity and service

Comment: Try posting the stacktrace...

Comment: There is no stacktrace generated, I was also looking for the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to call unbindService before calling stopService. I think that is the reason. If the service is in binded state, then it cannot be stopped unless it is unbineded and that might be the reason for your activity getting closed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `startService(intent2)` from your **code to start bind service** .The service is binded by calling `bindService(intent2, mServerConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)` no need of calling `startService(intent2)`.And also to unbind the service just use `unbindService(mServerConn)`

Comment: service doesnt start if i use bindService(intent2, mServerConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE) only but on destroy is called on unbindService(mServerConn)

Comment: then there is something seriously wrong in binding the service ..I am using service to bind and unbind and its working fine for me ..so plz post the code for Activity and service

Comment: even if i use normal background running service it closes the activity

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

}
```

You have overridden `onPause()` and you are **not calling super.onPause()`inside it**. This will cause your app to crash when`onPause()` is called.

You say there is no stacktrace, but that isn't correct. You are probably filtering the logcat and missing it. Make sure you aren't filtering the logcat and you will see the error in the logcat.

Comment: I have added super.onPause in it but still the activity closes the logcat only the below error

Comment: A/libc(8395): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1), thread 8395